# How to add ASP.NET MVC model class to unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api

I'm learning how to use Web API to make sure my online game is safe. I already connected to my API but I want to use my model class in unity 2d project. how to add ASP.NET MVC model class to my unity  project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class library in which you define your models. Then reference that class library from both your Unity project and your API project.

Comment: @derHugo I couldn't do what you said :/ The problem is I couldn't export my asp.net project as "package.json" and add unity project and I couldn't find an example video can you explain a little more or pass me a video if you know thank you again

Comment: @whyme You don't export it .. just as said create s local relative link to it in your manifest that's all .. you need to **add** the `package.json` file

Comment: @whyme please accept derHugo's more exhaustive answer instead, mine was more like a pot shot.

Comment: @CodeCaster bro I picked your comment is answer so Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You should make your let's name it `SharedlLibrary` fulfill the requirements to be a [Custom Unity Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPackages.html) (see also [Packages](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Packages.html) in general) -> It is recommended to stick to the [Recommended Package Layout](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/cus-layout.html) to the needed extend - the minimum requirement would simply be **adding** the [Package manifest (=`package.json`)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-manifestPkg.html) file at folder root.

So that you can use it in your Unity project as a [Custom Unity Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPackages.html). This would be the main part answering your question hopefully. You can simply reference any [local folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui-local.html), [git repository](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui-giturl.html) or even just a [subfolder of a git repository](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-git.html#subfolder) as a package so on re-compilation of your Unity code it also re-fetches these package contents.

---

But for making your repository live easier I would have a single repository with a structure like e.g.

```
YourRepositoryRootFolder
|
|- Unity Project
|  |- Assets
|  |- Packages
|  |- ...
|
|- Asp.Net Backend
|  |- Program.cs
|  |- ...
|  |- SharedLibrary
|  |  |- package.json (this you create with content according to API above)
|  |  |- YourModels.cs
|  |  |- ...
```

So that in Unity you reference the `SharedLibrary` folder as a [local package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui-local.html) in the

```
   YourRepositoryRootFolder/Unity Project/Packages/manifest.json
```

using a relative path like e.g.

```
   "my.stuff.sharedlibrary": "file:../../../SharedLibrary",
```

This way you can still have and maintain everything in a single repository.

Comment: I'm sorry  but it will be mobile game but before ı try it is it same to use mobile game? also im sorry again because ım still a beginer, you mean second part of your answer ı can add my asp.net backend project to my unity project as you shared structure  @derHugo

Comment: Sorry jumped into assumptions ;) It would work the same yes. In that case you would of course skip the last two points, simply reference your shared stuff in both the AspNet and your Unity application. You could even host the SharedLibrary folder within the aspnet again and skip even the `ActualBackend.sln` ... it still needs to have the `package.json` file and you need to reference the correct folder path in the Unity manifest.json

Comment: @whyme updated the answer according to this